# How to call function on change anything on full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i am using full calendar jquery plugin,i want to call function on change anything like delete event,change event,add event,resize event

for reference http://fullcalendar.io

Comment: you will have to use different calbacks in order to achieve this, there is no such function for now that does provide you with onchange function.

Comment: is there any function that will fire on change event object(clientevent)

Comment: `eventAfterAllRender` will not solve the problem as you might resize the events and even drag and drop 'em as well, in those cases the `eventAfterAllRender` will not work you will have to achieve this using other functions.

Comment: it is working fine,eventAfterAllRender is calling on drag,resize also @valarmorghulis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use following method of full calendar

```
eventAfterAllRender (callback)
```

for more information [This link](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/)

I hopes it's may helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the Fullcalendar's function for your purpose.take a look at extending in JQuery here: [extending](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: sorry not getting your answer